# ConnectionString Transforms when deploying to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

#### What I'm up against

In my current project, I'm trying to deploy a .NET MVC project to Elastic Beanstalk on AWS. I've usually worked with Azure in the past and I'm having a difficulty tracking down information on Config transforms for connection strings.

#### What I've tried

I *have* found that I can change/manipulate AppSettings, but I don't really like the idea of moving my connectionstrings to appsettings if I don't absolutely have to.

Additionally, I don't want to do a Web.Release.config transform with the production environment because this project will likely be published to development, staging, and production environments, all with separate connection strings.

I've also tried to look at ebextensions, but I haven't quite been pointed in the direction of changing connection strings in anything.

#### What I'm looking for

Does anyone have any solutions they've used or any resources (blogs, guides, etc) they could recommend?

#### tl;dr

Looking for a way to do ConnectionString transforms for an ASP.NET MVC project deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any guides but here are some steps you can use to achieve what you want to do:

1. Create new configurations for each environment using the Configuration Manager
2. Add additional config transforms (right click the Web.config and then "Add Config Transform")
3. Set the connection string transformation values for each environment in the config transforms
4. Create a publish profile (right click on the Asp.Net Mvc project and click Publish)
5. Set the Publish method to "Web Deployment Package"
6. Set configuration to match the environment you want to use which will automatically apply correct config transform
7. Publish package to some location and then upload as a new version to your Elastic Beanstalk
8. Repeat creating the Configurations and Publish Profiles for each environment

Just a note, connection strings are parameterized in the deployment package and the actual value will appear in the parameters.xml file in the deployment zip package and the Web.config will simply have a replacement token. When deploying the package, Elastic Beanstalk will apply the parameterization to the Web.config.

Comment: The Web Deploy Package is the correct solution for us. The missing piece for me was the awsdeploy tool picking up the package and deploying from there, if that makes sense.

Comment: @KevinR. but didn't this solution still leave you with multiple transforms that you didn't really want?

I'm looking for something similar but being able to set the connection string as part of the Beanstalk environment.

So far I've found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917010/accessing-asp-net-mvc-variables-in-elastic-beanstalk-web-config but this seems to just be for AppSettings (and like you I want to continue using connection strings).

Comment: Are you using framework or core? It's a lot easier with core