# How to use Elastic Beanstalk environment properties in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, web-config, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to set up a multi environment Elastic Beanstalk ASP MVC solution.

Environment specific settings, such as connection strings and remote endpoints are stored in web.config.

[This article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html?icmpid=docs_elasticbeanstalk_console) leads me to believe that it should be possible to define properties on the Configuration "Modify software" -> "Environment properties" section of my Elastic Beanstalk environment configuration. The article is linked from that page.

To test this, I created an Elastic Beanstalk application with a single environment. On the Configuration -> "Modify software" page I defined one property `KEY1` with the value `custom1`

I then set up a new ASP MVC 5 .NET 4.6.1 web solution in Visual Studio 2017, with a single controller/action which simply loops through `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` and `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables( )` and renders them on the page.

In web.config I have

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="KEY1" value="default1"/>
    <add key="KEY2" value="default2"/>
    ...
</appSettings>
```

When I view the page on my elasticbeanstalk.com URL, I don't see the value from my environment properties! Instead I see:

```
KEY1 = default1
KEY2 = default2
```

Where I would have expected

```
KEY1 = custom1
KEY2 = default2
```

And in the output of `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables( )` I don't see `KEY1` or `KEY2`

The documentation explicitly says that

> Elastic Beanstalk doesn't support passing environment variables to .NET Core applications and multiple-application IIS deployments that use a deployment manifest

But this is a classic ASP MVC 5 application.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [in this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917010/accessing-asp-net-mvc-variables-in-elastic-beanstalk-web-config).

What I was missing was the fact that the param will only be added if it does not already exists in the `<appsettings>` part of `web.config`.

This was a surprise, coming from Octopus Deploy where the keys *has* to exists in `<appSettings>`.